# Is weblogic 10.3.6 data source connection pool maximum capacity per domain or server?

Tags: database, connection, jdbc, weblogic

My WLS server is connecting to an Oracle DB that has a maximum concurrent connection limit of 3.

I have created a data source in WebLogic and set the "Maximum Capacity" value to 3.

Is this value calculated across the domain or per server?

Answer (score 1):

The "maximum capacity" setting is per server. So the maximum outbound connections is "maximum capacity" * the number of target servers for the data source.

Answer provided by [oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/message/11336576#11336576).